# How to change size of regression line in panel.abline in Lattice?

Tags: r, regression, lattice

Ok, I've been looking for a function that helps me change the size of my regression line in xyplot. I tried `panel.abline(reg = coef, size = 2)` but it doesn't work.

Hear is my code,

```
Plot.col <- brewer.pal(8,"Set1")[8][cut(Std.Change, c(-2.5,2.5), label = FALSE)]
Plot.ord <- rev(order(Std.Change))

coef <- coef(lm(Std.ModernC ~ Std.Change, data = Std.DataReg))
xyplot(Std.ModernC ~ Std.Change, data = Std.DataReg[Plot.ord, ], type = c("p", "g"), col = "blue",pch = 21, fill = Plot.col[Plot.ord], cex = 1.3,panel = function(...) {
  panel.xyplot(...)
  panel.abline(reg = coef, col = "blue")})
```

In ggplot, it is very easy to change for the size of regression line, by just setting `geom_abline(size = 2)`

I'm still learning lattice, and I don't know if there's a function for that, or whatsoever.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
panel.abline(reg = coef, lwd = 2)
```

(although `lwd` ("line width") is listed in the help page, in order to figure this out you would probably have to be familiar with base graphics, which this specification mimics)

Comment: @ALSTAT consider accepting Ben's answer as the correct answer by clicking the grey check mark below the answer score.